# Using the aws sdk be a reasonable option in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

For using AWS DynamoDB in a Java project, I want to know if it'll makes sense to just go with aws sdk "[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.html)" as opposed to "[spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb)" community module.

I know I'll miss all the spring related eco-system capabilities if I chose "[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.html)".  However, could just using the aws sdk be a reasonable option in a spring boot application?

Answer (score 1):

I have a spring boot application that uses DynamoDB. I highly recommend using Amazon's native [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) for object persistence. It's an excellent framework, its well documented, easy to understand and has a lot of functionality.

To my mind its a 'no-brainer' to use Amazon's SDK as you can be sure they will keep the projects in sync (i.e. your persistence and object persistence SDK are provided by the same organisation, and therefore they will be maintained together).

EDIT: Unless you and your team are just comfortable and experienced with spring, in which case that's fine too!